# rabbitmq Per-Queue Message TTL can't work

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to discard the messages in the rabbitmq queues when they are not consumed after 3 minutes.
According to official doc http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html   ;

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy TTL ".*" '{"message-ttl":60000}' --apply-to queues
```

I just set this command, but it don't work as I expect.

If the policy is called when the queues are empty，then the incoming messages will be discarded after expired. Otherwise, the old messages and new messages will be keep in the queues.

Any guys know why ?

Comment: What do you mean didn't work as expect, in question u mentioned for 3 min i.e 180000ms , while in the command you are setting 60000ms i.e 1 min.

Comment: I encounter that one consumer service is down, an the recieve queue of this service is flooded by gigantic messages.  I want to discard them when they arrived but have not consume after 3 minutes; In fact ,I called "rabbitmqctl set_policy TTL ".*" '{"message-ttl":180000}' --apply-to queues". But if some messages are in the queues , this command will not delete them.